# Excluding everything but a specific file name in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've got a messy workspace that I can't clean up, I want to exclude pretty much every file in it save for some I've made.

I have some files that start with a prefix like this:

affsplantident.psc

that I want to keep in the workspace, but I also have a tonne of other .psc files I don't want to see.

`"**/*.psc"` excludes everything

`"**/affs*.psc"` excludes my files and leaves everything else

However `"!**/affs*.psc"` does not exclude everything but the affs* files

Is there a way I can exclude everything BUT the psc files that start with affs ?

Comment: This comes close: `"**/[^a][^f][^f]*" : true,` - maybe close enough?  But I can't add the extension for some reason.  I think it used to work.

Comment: See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/869 there is no real built-in way to exclude all EXCEPT certain files/directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
"files.exclude": {
  "**/*.[^p][^s][^c]": true,

  "**/[^a]*" : true,
  "**/a[^f]*" : true,
  "**/af[^f]*" : true
}
```

That seems to work unless the files you want are in folders and not at the top level.  It is a hard problem - perhaps you want to upvote the issue I linked to in the comments above.